# Typescript build fails when using js node_modules using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

I hit this error regularly and I haven't ever got to the bottom of what is happening properly. Here I'm referencing puppeteer from a typescript file - but it's unable to work with a js file because it's found an unexpected symbol - it appears that it isn't able to parse es6 symbols.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/find-up/index.js Module
> parse failed: Unexpected token (29:38) You may need an appropriate
> loader to handle this file type.
>
> `while (true) {` 
> `const foundPath = await runMatcher({...options, cwd: directory});`

---

**Node version** 12.6.1
**TS version**   4.0.2

**`tsconfig.json`**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost",
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "sourceMap": true,

    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "app/index.tsx"
  ],
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts",
    "app/**/*.tsx",
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "app/types.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

**webpack config**

```js
/**
 * Base webpack config used across other specific configs
 */

const path = require('path');
const {
  dependencies: externals
} = require('../app/package.json');

module.exports = {
  module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          loaders: ['react-hot-loader/webpack', 'ts-loader'],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          // exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
              plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',

    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1114
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },

  // https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      'node_modules',
    ]
  },

  plugins: [],

  externals: Object.keys(externals || {})
};
```

Comment: what version of Node are you running

Comment: @Pointy 12.16.1

Comment: Well I guess a more useful question would have been, can you do a spread syntax statement from the Node REPL in your current version. *edit* It looks like it should certainly work in Node 12.16.1.

Comment: @Pointy I can, does seem to work in 12.6.1